# Where can I read about general AppEngine downtime and status?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm experiencing severe latency today. [This status page](https://code.google.com/status/appengine) reports no problems, but my query which took 59 seconds just now indicates otherwise (usually takes milliseconds). Also the task queues take forever to process. Are there any other pages or forums where one can see or discuss AppEngine downtime or latency issues?

I have checked my quotas and all are listed as "Okay" in the Rate-column

Comment: I suggest you check the google-group related to Appengine. Other than that, it may be some appengine related issue (free service with loads of users? you don't say!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a downtime notification google group: [google appengine downtime notify](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-appengine-downtime-notify)
but I think your best bet when querying is to use [appengine google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-appengine)

Comment: Others seem to be having latency issues in the last few hours too: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/aQQhxsLqNnI

Comment: The appenginge google group is "officially moving to stack overflow" (which is a bit strange since the two are not equal type of sites)

Comment: For Q&A type stuff they've moved to SO (last year), but for long discussions and issues the forum is there.

Comment: Just received update from downtime notify: "We are currently experiencing an issue with Google App Engine Datastore and some applications are experiencing increased latency on read and write operations, especially for consistent reads.
For everyone who is affected, we apologize - we know you count on Google to work for you and we're working hard to restore normal operation. We will provide an update within an hour with current details, and if available an estimated time for resolution." Good idea to subscribe to downtime notify.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest place to check if something is going on with App Engine is its status console:

http://code.google.com/status/appengine

There you'll be able to check the distinct App Engine components, and quickly check if there are incidents related to your problem.

As Bert says, you can also subscribe to the [notify list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-appengine-downtime-notify), but notify e-mails come out after the fact (as problems need to be confirmed and mails composed).

Comment: http://code.google.com/status/appengine is not accurate on purpose.  Perhaps it's a PR/Marketing thing.